# Error when extending JavaScript Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I had a `Worker` class which accepts a callback, but I wanted to remove the callback by making it a `Promise`, so I can just do `new Worker(stuff, otherStuff).then(function() { ... });`

To do this, I used the `extends` keyword.

At first, I got the `ReferenceError: this is not defined` error at the `this.a = a;` assignment, but I found out that that was because I had to call `super();`

Now, it gives `TypeError: this.resolve is not a function` at the `this.resolve({output: 'ok'});` line, so I tried to forcibly add `this.resolve` and `this.reject` functions, but the error won't go away.

This is the (heavily simplified) code:

```
class Worker extends Promise {
    constructor(a, b) {
        super((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('inside super');
            this.resolve = resolve;
            this.reject = reject;
        });

        console.log('start constructing');

        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;

        console.log('A: ' + JSON.stringify(a));
        console.log('B: ' + JSON.stringify(b));

        this.doStuff();

        if (!this.status) {
            this.resolve({output: 'ok'});
        } else {
            this.reject('There was an error');
        }
    }

    doStuff() {}
}

let a = {x: 1};
let b = {z: 2};

console.log('before creation');
let w = new Worker(a, b);
console.log('after creation');
w.then(function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```

I am using node 6.1.0, which [appears](http://node.green/) to support `Promise` subclassing... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually it's `this.resolve = resolve;` that should throw - because `this` is not yet initialised before the `super` call returns

Comment: Can you show us your actual code? I don't get why you are subclassing `Promise` here or what part is asynchronous after all.

Comment: The actual code uses a library (kue) which implements an async queue, and uses it to process a number of "tests". When the processing is finished, it calls this.resolve, if there's an error somewhere, it calls this.reject

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a good reason to subclass `Promise`. Just make a normal function that returns a standard promise.

Comment: The actual code can be found [here](https://github.com/algorithm-ninja/shuriken/blob/0f6741bcd32a00bb71f8266ba0b9ede50a5a7774/shuriken/evaluators/BatchEvaluator.js) but keep in mind that the `BatchEvaluator` class is still the old version (with the callback)

Comment: OK, I can't claim to have understood the whole code, but it looks like instead of taking that callback argument in your constructor, `run` should return a `Promise`. Btw, is `run()` supposed to be called multiple times (and if so, what's supposed to happen with the callback)?

Comment: Thanks. I was actually planning on making the run method private and calling it from the constructor, but if there's no way to make `BatchEvaluator` a promise then I will keep the run method public and make it return a promise.

Comment: There probably is a way, all I'm saying is that it doesn't make much sense. Your `BatchEvaluator` instances don't seem to have any public fields besides that `run()` method, and you'd be better off to just make it a promise-returning `batchEvaluate` function with lots of local subfunctions (instead of a `class` with lots of private methods)

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is **avoid to extend primitive classes** as they are subjects to changes. Extending them would put your own class to the browser/engine mercy.

When you try to extend Promise class, `this` will not be defined in the constructor as most of the engines nowadays don't support sub-classing Promise.

Moreover, a worker is not a promise. A worker is supposed to work and make a promise.

A solution is to use the wrapper or factory pattern rather than inheritance.

For example, you can define a getter `promise` in your `Worker` class that would create a new `Promise` instance and return it.

Comment: Remove the first two paragraphs and you'll get an upvote :-) The native classes are designed to be extendable, and the rules for that are well defined.

Comment: @Bergi I'm not posting for upvotes.

Moreover, as native classes and any of native codes, objects, etc. are not written by the user him/herself, they are at the mercy of the provider - such as those who wrote the javascript/typescript engine.

No matter how people claim that such class is designed to be extendable bla bla bla, human are not trustable by nature. I learned it a hard way so don't try to say otherwise.

Comment: All JS code is at the mercy of the engine implementor and executor. The native classes are well-defined in the ECMAScript language specification, and there's no reason not to trust that one. And you cannot write useful JS code without using any builtins, so there's no reason to trust the extensibility of classes less than, say, the `exec` method of regular expression objects.

Comment: @Bergi Jul 3 Specifications are reference, not implementation. Most of the time, specifications are way ahead of the actual implementation. As a result, polyfills were made. Those implementations would or wouldn't follow the specifications depending on the engine limitation. So, even though the polyfills do their job, it doesn't mean they live up to the specifications letter-by-letter.

I've learned the hard way not to ever trust any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

function serializeError(error){return{message:error.message||"",name:error.name||"",stack:error.stack||""}}class NativeResolver{constructor(){this.resolve;this.reject;this.promise=new Promise(((resolve,reject)=>{this.resolve=resolve;this.reject=reject}))}}function assertCast(condition){if(!condition){throw new Error("Failed assertion")}return condition}const ReservedMessageTypes={RESPONSE_TYPE:"***response",ERROR_TYPE:"***error"};function isGeneratedMessage(messageType){return messageType.substr(0,3)==="***"}function throwIfReserved(messageType){if(isGeneratedMessage(messageType)){throw new Error(`Unexpected reserved message type: '${messageType}'`)}}class MessagePipe{constructor(targetOrigin,target,rethrowErrors=true){if(!target){const frame=document.querySelector(`iframe[src^='${targetOrigin}']`);if(!frame||!frame.contentWindow){throw new Error("Unable to locate target content window.")}target=assertCast(frame.contentWindow)}this.target*=target;this.targetOrigin*=targetOrigin;this.rethrowErrors=rethrowErrors;this.logClientError=object=>console.error(JSON.stringify(object));this.messageHandlers*=new Map;this.pendingMessages_=new Map;this.nextMessageId_=0;this.messageListener_=m=>this.receiveMessage_(m);console.assert(this.target_!==window,"target !== window");window.addEventListener("message",this.messageListener_)}registerHandler(messageType,handler){throwIfReserved(messageType);if(this.messageHandlers_.has(messageType)){throw new Error(`A handler already exists for ${messageType}`)}this.messageHandlers_.set(messageType,handler)}async sendMessage(messageType,message={}){try{return await this.sendMessageImpl(messageType,message)}catch(errorResponse){const error=new Error(`${messageType}: ${errorResponse.message}`);error.name=errorResponse.name||"Unknown Error";error.stack+=`\nError from ${this.targetOrigin_}\n${errorResponse.stack}`;throw error}}async sendMessageImpl(messageType,message={}){throwIfReserved(messageType);const messageId=this.nextMessageId_++;const resolver=new NativeResolver;this.pendingMessages_.set(messageId,resolver);this.postToTarget_(messageType,message,messageId);return resolver.promise}detach(){window.removeEventListener("message",this.messageListener_)}handleMessageResponse_(messageType,message,messageId){const{RESPONSE_TYPE:RESPONSE_TYPE,ERROR_TYPE:ERROR_TYPE}=ReservedMessageTypes;const resolver=this.pendingMessages_.get(messageId);if(messageType===RESPONSE_TYPE){resolver.resolve(message)}else if(messageType===ERROR_TYPE){this.logClientError(message);resolver.reject(message)}else{console.error(`Response for message ${messageId} received with invalid message type ${messageType}`)}this.pendingMessages_.delete(messageId)}async callHandlerForMessageType_(messageType,message,messageId){const{RESPONSE_TYPE:RESPONSE_TYPE,ERROR_TYPE:ERROR_TYPE}=ReservedMessageTypes;let response;let error=null;let sawError=false;try{response=await this.messageHandlers_.get(messageType)(message)}catch(err){sawError=true;error=err;response=serializeError(err)}this.postToTarget_(sawError?ERROR_TYPE:RESPONSE_TYPE,response,messageId);if(sawError&&this.rethrowErrors){this.logClientError(error);throw error}}receiveMessage_(event){const e=event;if(typeof e.data!=="object"||!e.data||typeof e.data.type!=="string"){return}const{messageId:messageId,type:type,message:message}=e.data;const{ERROR_TYPE:ERROR_TYPE}=ReservedMessageTypes;if(e.origin!==this.targetOrigin_&&this.targetOrigin_!=="*"){return}if(isGeneratedMessage(type)&&this.pendingMessages_.has(messageId)){this.handleMessageResponse_(type,message,messageId);return}if(isGeneratedMessage(type)){console.error(`Response with type ${type} for unknown message received.`);return}if(!this.messageHandlers_.has(type)){const error=new Error(`No handler registered for message type '${type}'`);const errorResponse=serializeError(error);this.postToTarget_(ERROR_TYPE,errorResponse,messageId);return}this.callHandlerForMessageType_(type,message,messageId)}postToTarget_(messageType,message,messageId){const messageWrapper={messageId:messageId,type:messageType,message:message||{}};this.target_.postMessage(messageWrapper,this.targetOrigin_)}}

Comment: Can you explain how this is related in any way to the question from a half-decade ago?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).